# How to prevent a path from being filled (again)?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am drawing some shapes on a canvas element. The first element is a path, which should not get filled at all. I know I can set fillStyle to none, but it gets filled twice.
Here is some example code (also on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jakschu/CjcZ6/)):

```
can = document.getElementById('can');
ctx = can.getContext('2d');

function drawPoint(x,y){
    ctx.arc(x,y,12,0,Math.PI*2,false);
    ctx.fillStyle ='rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)';
    ctx.fill();
}

function shape(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.2)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(10,10);
    ctx.lineTo(100,30);
    ctx.lineTo(30,200)
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.fill();
}

shape();

drawPoint(30,12);
```

This is just an example code, to illustrate the problem I am facing.
When I draw the shape afterwards, the point is in the background. So this won't work. I also searched for resources on how the fill method works but couldn't find anything useful.

So how can I draw the shape without filling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't call `fill()`...

For example, if you want your method reusable you can use a flag:

```
function shape(fill){
    fill = fill || false;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,255,0,0.2)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(10,10);
    ctx.lineTo(100,30);
    ctx.lineTo(30,200)
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
    if (fill) ctx.fill();
}
```

Now you can call:

```
draw();     /// won't fill
draw(true); /// fills
```

Also add a `beginPath()` to this method or else it will just add to the path of the first shape (which perhaps is what you mean?):

```
function drawPoint(x,y){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,12,0,Math.PI*2,false);
    ctx.fillStyle ='rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2)';
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Hope this helps (and that I didn't misunderstand your question)!

**[Modified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/CjcZ6/1/)**

Comment: The beginPath method fixed my code. To me the arc somehow was no path. I was trying to fix this for about 2h...

Comment: @jakschu yeah, the arc can be tricky as it's easy to think of it as a closed circle. In any case, glad I could help!